# NameError: name 'pytesseract' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, path, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

Pytesseract is not recognized. I have tried all fixes documented online, including adding Tesseract-OCR to my Path variables, incorporating the `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'` command path in my script, uninstalling and reinstalling pytesseract and tesseract.

Comment: Could you show me your code?

Comment: after you add Tesseract to your path,you needn't to use ``tesseract_cmd=xxxxxx``

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA edited to include code

Answer (score 0):

In the line 23 
    `vpnbookpassword = pytesseract.image_to_string(pwdi)`
there you have mentioned `pytesseract.image_to_string` but you have imported image_to_string 
`from pytesseract import image_to_string` and not pytesseract so it could not find pytesseract.
So writing it as `vpnbookpassword = image_to_string(pwdi)` would solve the issue